# Is "the dairy" referring to a specific location?

Tags: grimm, real-location

In S2E07 of *Grimm*, Nick states that Juliette's father used to take her to watch fireworks at the dairy.

Is this referring to a specific location by this name or a generic dairy?

Many locations in the show are correlated to actual locations in and around Portland which is why I ask.

Answer (score 2):

They could be referencing the Alpenrose Dairy, which used to do holiday themed events.  Christmas was a big one for them, but I don't know if they still do any.  6149 SW Shattuck Rd, Portland, OR 97221

Comment: Looking at their [events calendar](http://www.alpenrose.com/pages/Calendar.html) it appears that they are still very much active in doing themed events.

Comment: This site seems to agree. They claim it was "confirmed on twitter" but I've not been able to find anything to back that up. The site seems very reliable otherwise; http://www.mysouthwaterfront.com/2012/10/grimm-s2-ep-7-bottle-imp-portland.html